# This is indeed a rather strange unupvoting pattern, Holmes

Tags: support, voting, up-votes

A few days ago I've read @Artes in chat "talking" about some inexplicable *unupvoting* activity going on.

Then, it happened today in some of my questions/answers, so I brought the issue into chat and there discovered this case, which I think is [the most clear example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1744/193) . It comes from @OleksandrR.

The facts (timeline as I understand it)

1. Feb 14, 15:11 Olek posted the answer
2. Feb 14, 15:16 The [grace/confusion period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40253/so-says-i-made-a-change-that-i-didnt-make) is over. No upvotes received yet
3. Feb 14, 15:30 [First upvote received](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/312/oleksandr-r?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=4). (and 12 more within a 24 hrs period, Total up to feb 15 : 13)
4. Feb 23, 16:05 Answer accepted
5. Feb 24, 12:07 An upvote. Total 14
6. Feb 26, 00:57 An upvote. Total 15
7. Apr 13, 00:53 An upvote, Total 16
8. Apr 13, 00:58 The last (and thus all) upvotes [are locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80762/why-do-votes-get-locked). They can't be undone if the Q isn't edited
9. Aug 20, 12:51 **The answer receives an unupvote**, while all the votes were locked and no editing happened in between. (Total: 15)

What really bothers me is that the *unupvoted* answers/questions are quite good, with no controversial material (nor infix) inside. So I think there are no objective reasons to reconsider an already issued upvote.

So ... What is going on here? How is this kind of activity possible?

PS: Is instead [Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions) the right site for this question?

Comment: Please comment whether your Q&A were targeted by this behavior.

Comment: What happens if an upvoting user gets removed?

Comment: Shortly after the unupvote, Mr.Wizard posted a new answer. I would consider it perfectly reasonable if he was the unupvoter in this case, because indeed the answer *was not useful* to him on version 7 (due to the problems mentioned in his post, which are not obvious at first glance, and could foreseeably lead to an unwarranted upvote before the limitations became evident). However, this does mean that moderators appear to be subject to different vote-locking rules than everyone else, and I can't see any good reason why that should be the case: a moderator's votes are the same as anyone else's!

Comment: @OleksandrR. Note that yours is only an example. I've been unupvoted _on questions_!

Comment: Of course, if Mr.Wizard's (absolutely justified) vote wasn't implicated here, then there are no clues to why this might occur and so the problem remains. The vast majority of the unupvotes come only after editing, so this particular case may simply be a surprising exception due to nonuniformity in the voting rules and not representative of the bulk of the cases. It'd be helpful to have confirmation from other moderators as to whether such an inconsistency actually exists.

Comment: -17 for "(nor infix)"! >:-S  ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was waiting for you :)

Answer (score 3):

Though I cannot recall with absolute certainty I believe that in this case Oleksandr is correct, and the vote/un-vote was mine.  It is possible to make a "ninja" vote change by making a trivial edit to the post, changing the vote, and exactly undoing the edit within the five minute edit window.  This causes the edit to be removed entirely, but the vote (change) remains.

Comment: I got the wrong "reference" but I know that this is stated somewhere on Meta.SO.  No time to find it now.

Comment: Ok. That could explain this specific case, but (for example) this question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8607/what-does-equationallogicfindcounterexample-do (and two more) received an unupvote today. I can't think of a reason ...

Comment: @belisarius I un-vote sparingly; the rest of the actions are not mine.  Unfortunately I cannot try to figure it out right now.